# subversion prevent listing of a repository in folder with SVNParentPath

Tags: svn, permissions, access-control

I have several repositories on my domain at: svn.domain.com

It will list the repositories by the SVNParentPath configuration.

I would like to create user permission for each folder / repository, but I want to remove that repository from the listing if a user does not have permission to access it.

This is mainly for outside persons that need to only have access to one given repository, and should not see the other projects that we are working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion itself doesn't handle the permissions - You need to configure the permissions in the apache server that is fronting the access to subversion:

```
<Directory /usr/local/svn/repo>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName intranet
  AuthUserFile /www/passwd/users
  AuthGroupFile /www/passwd/groups
  Require group customers
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from internal.com
  Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Of course you can use any authentication method [supported by apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#access)